# Can I post a file and data to a .net mvc web api controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have the following .net web api controller method that supports the posting of files to the server.

```
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFile()
            {
                var request = Request;
                if (!request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
                {
                    throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType));
                }

                var root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads");
                var provider = new MultipartFileStreamProvider(root);

                var task = request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsy

nc(provider).ContinueWith(o =>
            {
                var finfo = new FileInfo(provider.FileData.First().LocalFileName);

                var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                File.Move(finfo.FullName,
                    Path.Combine(root,
                        guid + "_" + provider.FileData.First().Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", "")));

                return new HttpResponseMessage
                {
                    Content = new StringContent("File upload.")
                };
            });

            return task;
        }
```

This works well, however I would like to be able to include some metadata about the file as part of the post. At the moment I am have a different web api method for the metadata like

```
  public HttpResponseMessage PostTAG(TAG tag)
```

Which takes the information in the tag object and saves it to a data base. It would be much easier for my api clients if they could post the file and metadata together in one request. Is this possible in .net web api.

Comment: Perhaps you could extend HttpPostedFileBase and add your metadata. Then send that in your method call from the client code so you have the file and custom data.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, where your WEB API declare a parameter for the TAG data. The problems will be your client who post data to your WEB API. If your client using .NET to post data to your WEB API, .NET WebClient does not support posting file along with data

Hence you will need to use lower level HttpWebRequest such as this one

```
public string UploadFilesToRemoteUrl(string url, Dictionary<string, string> files, NameValueCollection nvc, string contenttype)
        {
            string boundary = "----------------------------" +
            DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");

            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest2 = (HttpWebRequest)GetWebRequest(new Uri(url)); //(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            SetProxy(httpWebRequest2);
            SetUserAgent(httpWebRequest2);
            httpWebRequest2.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
            httpWebRequest2.Timeout = WebRequestTimeout; // 60 second * miliseconds * 60 minutes = 1 hour
            httpWebRequest2.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest2.KeepAlive = true;
            httpWebRequest2.Credentials =
            System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            Stream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            byte[] boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");

            string formdataTemplate = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\";\r\n\r\n{1}";

            if (nvc != null)
            {
                foreach (string key in nvc.Keys)
                {
                    string formitem = string.Format(formdataTemplate, key, nvc[key]);
                    byte[] formitembytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formitem);
                    memStream.Write(formitembytes, 0, formitembytes.Length);
                }
            }

            memStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);

            string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\n\r\n";
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contenttype) == false)
            {
                headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\n" + contenttype + "\r\n";
            }

            string[] keys = nvc.AllKeys;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> key in files)
            {
                //string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, "file" + i, files[i]);
                //string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, "uplTheFile", files[i]);
                string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, key.Key, key.Value);
                byte[] headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);

                memStream.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);

                FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(key.Value, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[buffsize];

                int bytesRead = 0;

                while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    memStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    int progress = Convert.ToInt32((memStream.Length * 100) / fileStream.Length);
                    ReportProgress(key.Value, progress);
                }

                memStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
                fileStream.Close();
                if (MonitoredDownload != null) MonitoredDownload.OnComplete(key.Value);
                buffer = null;
                headerbytes = null;
            }

            httpWebRequest2.ContentLength = memStream.Length;

            Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest2.GetRequestStream();
            memStream.Position = 0;
            byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[buffsize];
            int bytereads = 0;
            while ((bytereads = memStream.Read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                requestStream.Write(tempBuffer, 0, bytereads);
            }

            //memStream.Read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
            memStream.Close();
            memStream.Dispose();
            //requestStream.Write(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
            requestStream.Dispose();

            WebResponse webResponse2 = httpWebRequest2.GetResponse();
            //SaveCookie(webResponse2, new Uri(url).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority));
            Stream stream2 = webResponse2.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream2);
            string str = reader2.ReadToEnd();
            reader2.Close();
            reader2.Dispose();

            stream2.Close();
            stream2.Dispose();
            webResponse2.Close();

            httpWebRequest2 = null;
            webResponse2 = null;
            tempBuffer = null;
            return str;
        }
```

TO use it, simply call

```
Dictionary<string,string> dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
dict.Add("file1","c:\\myfile1.jpg");
NamuValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
nvc.Add("GPSPosition","somegpsvalue");
nvc.Add("CameraModel","somecameramodel");
UploadFilesToRemoteUrl("http://www.remoteurl.com/upload", dict, metadata, "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n");
```

The above code excerpt is gotten from WebScraper project at http://www.sorainnosia.com/Projects#WS